# The status of Urdu in Pakistan versus the status of Hindi in India

Tags: india, pakistan, languages

How can we compare the status of Urdu in Pakistan, with the status of Hindi in India before and after 1971 (the split of Pakistan)?

The Internet says that Urdu is the national language of Pakistan, but Hindi is not the national language of India. However, practically, both of them are the lingua franca in their respective countries.

How are they dissimilar according to the constitutions of their respective countries?

**Note:**

I am comparing Pakistan and India. I am comparing Urdu in Pakistan with Hindi in India.

I am not comparing Urdu and Hindi in India. I am not comparing Urdu and Hindi in Pakistan.

Answer (score 8):

The question has some false premises and also overlooks a central fact about the languages in question.

First of all, [Urdu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urdu) and Hindi are basically mutually intelligible regional dialects of the same language written in different scripts. Urdu began to differentiate from Hindi when Muslim migrants arrived in Pakistan starting around the 1100s CE, but was not a distinct literary language until the 1700s CE.

> Urdu (/ˈʊərduː/;[11] Urdu: اُردُو, ALA-LC: Urdū) is an Indo-Aryan
> language spoken chiefly in South Asia. It is the national language and
> lingua franca of Pakistan, where it is also an official language
> alongside English. In India, Urdu is an Eighth Schedule language whose
> status and cultural heritage is recognized by the Constitution of
> India; it also has an official status in several Indian states. In
> Nepal, Urdu is a registered regional dialect.
>
> The Urdu language has been described as a Persianized register of the
> Hindustani language; Urdu and Hindi share a common Sanskrit- and
> Prakrit-derived vocabulary base, phonology, syntax, and grammar,
> making them mutually intelligible during colloquial communication.
> While formal Urdu draws literary, political, and technical vocabulary
> from Persian, formal Hindi draws these aspects from Sanskrit;
> consequently, the two languages' mutual intelligibility effectively
> decreases as the factor of formality increases.

Second, Hindi is one of the 15 official languages of India, so it is one of India's national languages, and Hindi is not "the lingua franca" of India, which is English (e.g., [the Supreme Court of India operates solely in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judiciary_of_India#Supreme_Court)).

Hindi is a regional language of India spoken most often more or less in Northwest India. It is not widely spoken in Southern India where languages in the Dravidian language family are predominant, nor in parts of India more or less immediately adjacent to Bangladesh. Hindi is, however, the most widely spoken of the Indo-Aryan languages ultimately derived from Sanskrit.

The areas in which the 15 official languages of India are most widely spoken can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_with_official_status_in_India):

[image]

By comparison, in Pakistan, the map of the predominant local languages of the county look like this:

[image]

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_Pakistan))

Note that four other languages in Pakistan are more widely spoken than Urdu, the official language other than English of the country. Urdu is the predominant local language only in a tiny area where the Indus River meets the Indian Ocean (which would have been a point of first contact for early British colonists in the region).

Punjabi and Urdu are both languages in the Indo-Aryan language family with a common source in Sanskrit, a bit like the common Latin source of the Romance language in Europe but at a greater time depth. They are not mutually intelligible (unlike Hindi and Urdu).

In terms of time depth of their common ancestor language, the separation between Punjabi and Urdu is roughly comparable to the separation between Italian and Welsh in Europe, but less than the time depth of the separation between Greek and Latin. But this time depth was somewhat mitigated by areal effects, i.e. from being spoken in regions that are geographically close to each other.

Urdu and not Punjabi became the official language of Pakistan as a result of British colonial era edicts and the subsequent force of inertia which Pakistan's founders embraced.

All of the main languages of Pakistan are Indo-Aryan except for Brahui (which is Dravidian), Pashto (which is Iranian) and Balochi (which is Iranian). Iranian and Indo-Aryan are sister branches of the Indo-Iranian branch of the Indo-European language family and are more closely related to each other than to the European branches of the Indo-European languages. Unsurprisingly, the Iranian languages, Pashto and Balochi, are spoken mostly near the Western border of Pakistan which is closest to Iran.

The Brahui language, spoken by a fairly small percentage of Pakistanis, but in a fairly large geographic area, is a Dravidian language and not an Indo-Aryan or Iranian language family member and is not even an Indo-European language. There is dispute over its origins, but the leading view based upon linguistic evidence is that it arrived ca. 1000 CE via elite dominance leading to language shift from what was probably previously a linguistically Balochi or other Iranian language family member (because genetically, the Brahui people's population genetics so no sign of Dravidian ancestry and are basically indistinguishable from other Balochi speaking people in terms of population genetics).

> How can we compare the status of Urdu in Pakistan with the status of
> Hindi in India before and after 1971 (the split of Pakistan)?

Urdu is, together with English, the national language of Pakistan and a lingua franca.

Hindi is one of many official languages of India and Urdu has some official status under the Indian constitution and in some Indian states, but not as one of the fifteen official national languages.

Before and after 1971, Urdu was one of the national languages of Pakistan, but Bengali, the predominant language of former East Pakistan (now Bangladesh) ceased to be national languages of Pakistan following the 1971 split.

> In a 1948 speech, Jinnah [ed. a founding father of Pakistan] declared that "Urdu alone would be the state
> language and the lingua franca of the Pakistan state", although at the
> same time he called for the Bengali language to be the official
> language of the Bengal province.

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Pakistan_(1947%E2%80%93present)))

> Urdu was chosen as an official language of Pakistan in 1947 as it was
> already the lingua franca for Muslims in north and northwest British
> India. . . . In 1973, Urdu was recognised as the sole national
> language of Pakistan – although English and regional languages were
> also granted official recognition.

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urdu))

This said, as a result of the colonial history of South Asia and the widespread use of the South Asian dialect of English as a linga fraca throughout South Asia, English is used that way in Pakistan as well and Pakistani elites are generally fluent in English, and both English and Urdu are official languages of Pakistan.

Comment: How related are Urdu and Punjabi? I'm asking because the latter seems to be the majority dialect/language in Pakistan. That might help improve the answer,. You could also add a similar map of Pakistan with the languages spoken there.

Comment: I can easily find [such distance graphs](https://termcoord.eu/2014/01/lexical-distance-languages-europe/) for European languages but not so much for those of Asia.

Comment: @Fizz I've never seen such a graph for Indo-Aryan languages, I've only seen it described in words.

Comment: There is not a consensus on how Indo-Aryan languages should be grouped into sub-families, although none put Punjabi and Urdu particularly close to each other. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Aryan_languages

Comment: That English is the lingua franca of Indian government does not preclude Hindi from also being a lingua franca.  Both of the native Marathi speakers whom I've asked about which languages they speak speak both Hindi and English.  Wikipedia suggests that English remains in official use in India because of resistance to the imposition of Hindi in the south, and it says that Hindi is the lingua franca of Northern India.  So it seems that the difference lies not so much in the plethora of official languages as in the resistance of speakers of some of those languages (notably the unrelated ones).

Comment: @phoog: and probably that Pakistan was at times more of a dictatorship than India, so they could more easily impose whatever the central gov't wanted "or else".

Comment: @Fizz Pakistan and India were both united by imperial force, and mountainous territory is notoriously prone to heterogeneity.  The language dimension is probably determinative.  It's easier for a lingua franca to take hold among speakers of related languages.

Comment: "In terms of time depth of their common ancestor language, the separation between Punjabi and Urdu is roughly comparable to the separation between Italian and Welsh": it looks to me rather like Punjabi and Urdu are far more recently differentiated than Welsh and Italian, namely that Italo-Celtic split into Italic and Celtic about 4000 years ago, and Punjabi and Urdu split somewhere between 3000 and 1500 years ago (it seems that it's less clear because there was more literacy, more proximity, and therefore less independence of development).

Comment: Was Urdu picked by the English due to its compatibility with Hindi?  Also, the English ruled India by promoting some groups over others.  Was Urdu more used by those groups?

Comment: @phoog "it says that Hindi is the lingua franca of Northern India." a language used predominantly in the region where Hindi is the majority language and immediately neighboring regions is not a lingua franca. "Italo-Celtic split into Italic and Celtic" I would date it about 1000 BCE-750 BCE +/- probably during the late Urnfield Culture. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urnfield_culture.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urdu#Colonial_period

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, the central thrust of your question is your comment:

> Even though both Urdu and Hindi are used as lingua franca, why is Urdu designated as the national language but Hindi is not?

## Some context

In the east (I am an Indian) we always seek multi-layered outlook and thinking, especially on contentious subjects.
So while politics is a changing scene with little stability, if we wish to seek something more stable and generally agreeable to all, we need to go deeper.

Beneath politics is history.
Beneath history is geography.
And beneath geography is geometry, the Platonic realm.

Roughly speaking we may say:

Politics: decades
History: centuries
Geography: millennia
Platonism: eternal

## Prehistory

So let's take Korea as an example. As a landmass it has almost certainly existed for millennia. It was divided into two Koreas after WWII. This naturally creates contention over who 'owns' the landmass, the North or the South.

In Russia-Ukraine it's more entangled. Something Russian may be said to be a thousand years old, whereas Ukraine is more recent. And Putin has thrown an extra twist in by now claiming that Russia started as 'Kievan Rus'. Notice there's a gambit here: Russia cannot be as easily 'de-existed' as Ukraine. So Russia lobs the existence prerogative to Ukraine and then swallows it up. (Or at least uses that to justify it.)

The situation is similar in India-Pakistan but with its own twists.

So it's important to look at the history and geography of these questions rather than simply taking the current political status as though it's a fact.

## Etymology

In today's world, Hindi, Hindu, and India(n) are all separate categories -language, religion, nationality/political entity - and mixing them up shows muddled thinking. But this separation is quite recent, and it's worthwhile looking at the language. In particular, the etymology is quite illuminating.

To start off, it's worth noting that 'Hindu' is not a word that can be traced to the Hindu scriptures! [The first use of 'Hinduism' is 1816 https://twitter.com/devduttmyth/status/1263700703387676673]
Just take a moment to let it sink in how bizarre that is.
Imagine 'Muslim' being not a word from Mohammed, or Jesus not being called 'the Christ', or Gautama being called 'Buddha'.
Yet the fundamental framing of Hindu(ism) is quite later, and exterior to what we now call the Hindu tradition.
Needless to say, therefore, that the BJP-style extreme Hindu nationalists (India's Putins) hate the creator of the word 'Hindu' since they cannot pretend that the term has existed forever
(see [Rajiv Malhotra](https://twitter.com/RajivMessage/status/1132797372281573376)).

So at the risk of some over-simplification, one would find that where liberals prefer to use 'India', nationalists try to interchange that with 'Hindu'.

Now a second twist: while the nationalists like Rajiv Malhotra want to push India as a Hindu land, they violently resent the word 'Hindustan' for multiple reasons. For example, -'istan' is a Muslim terminology (and of course Muslims are bad by definition!)  More importantly, situating 'Hindu' in a place necessarily situates it in a time. And so the pretense of something eternal going back to the Vedas that pre-date the universe stops being tenable. Most importantly, Hindustan-Pakistan equals in a pair would legitimize Pakistan, which of course they never want to do (like Putin legitimizing Ukraine).

So the nationalists tell multiple lies: a) Hindu is an original Hindu term and concept, but b) the original and proper name of India is of course not India (European) or Hindustan (Muslim/Arabic), but "Bharat" or "Jambu-Dweepa" or "Ram-rajya" or something else with a mythological background.

It's true these nationalist lies are created to counter other lies of the liberals in the congress party, but I won't go into that here. I'll only give a summary:

Congress-left-liberals want to emphasize India
BJP-right-nationalism want to emphasize Hindu

And if one notices that that is a category mismatch - a conflict of a political entity/country with a religion - then yes! That is very much the center of the culture war.

[Just to be honest: I have some sympathy and much aversion to both parties but of course for very different reasons.  Something like saying I don't like Hillary and I don't like Trump.]

So to summarize the path: in Sanskrit the word 'sindhu' (common noun) means 'river' or 'sea'. As a proper noun, it refers to the Indus river. [Notice the echoes of 'India' here? And the irony that almost the whole Indus is now in Pakistan.] The Muslim invaders referred to the land east of the Sindhu as the Sindhu area but in transliterating Sanskrit to Arabic/Turkish/Persian it became 'Hind', and then Hindustan. When the Europeans came, 'Hind' got latinized to India.

## Urdu

Let's turn now to Urdu.

Wikipedia says re. [Hindustani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindustani_language):

> Ancestors of the language were known as: Hindui, Hindavi, Zabān-e Hind (transl. 'Language of India'), Zabān-e Hindustan (transl. 'Language of Hindustan'), Hindustan ki boli (transl. 'Language of Hindustan'), Rekhta, and Hindi.[11][18] Its regional dialects became known as Zabān-e Dakhani in southern India, Zabān-e Gujari (transl. 'Language of Gujars') in Gujarat, and as Zabān-e Dehlavi or Urdu around Delhi.

So south Indian is Dakhani, western India is Gujari, and Delhi is Urdu.

Again, let that sink in: Urdu is the Delhi language of the Mughal kings.

And putting these two facts together:

- Urdu comes from India, specifically Delhi.
- Hindu comes from Arabia, i.e. the Pakistan or west of (modern) India

In some more detail:

From the first Muslim invaders of nearly a thousand years ago, until the Mughals about 500 years later, there was a significant shift. Earlier, it was just kill/rape/pillage/steal/convert by the sword. Later on, there was a much stronger intent to form and live by a new synthesized culture, which is when Hindustani/Urdu comes into existence.

This inclusive intent reached its peak with Akbar who even tried to formulate a new religion, Deen e ilahi, that was as acceptable to the locals (Hindus) as to the foreigners (Muslims).  And you may once again notice that region and religion are mixed up. As they very much were:

So in those days 'Hindu-stan' was very much like Afghan-istan, Tajik-istan, Uzbek-istan. And just as Afghan, Tajik, Uzbek and so on were and are ethnicities, so was Hindu, at least in intent.

Now if all this looks very mixed up, it is: a Hindu of those times was probably much more a North Indian of British India than a (religious) Hindu of today. I say British India because a North Indian of today and a Pakistani would have closer genetic makeup than a North and a South Indian.

Something India-like has certainly existed for millennia, but with different names. On the other hand, nothing like Pakistan existed before Jinnah and the Gandhi camp fell out with each other, in about the 1920s.

So unlike Korea, India the country got India the name and the considerably larger chunk of land. This made the Pakistan side more insecure. Insecurity always leads to a hardening of identity. So Pakistan much more imperatively had to have a national language than India did.

Note that in a sane world, the division of India and Pakistan would not have happened. Unfortunately, in our reality it happened, with one of the largest mass murders in recent history.
If we could go beyond that history to some ideal more lasting we would see that India-Pakistan had the same ideals, just with different names:
India calls it akhand bharat, Pakistan calls it ghazwa-e-hind.
Is is the same idea - an undivided land.
[It's important to use a correct name -- let's tentatively just say "S-E Asia"]

Comment: It's unclear to me how this actually answers the question. You've explained the historical context of the names "Urdu" and "Hindi", but I'm not seeing an explanation of why Urdu is the national language of Pakistan but Hindi isn't the national language of India, which is what the question is asking. Are you saying it's just because Indian nationalists don't like the name "Hindi"?

Comment: Thanks @F1Krazy for your efforts. The short form answer is the penultimate paragraph. India is a large diverse region. It can have a single language as meaningfully as Europe can!! Pakistan is a recent construct from the bickerings of Gandhi and Jinnah. It therefore more strongly needs to define its identity than India does. State religion, state language etc are all part of that identity definition struggle. For India teh Radcliffe line is a grievous wound. For Pakistan, the Radcliffe line is existential. [Also there were strong opposing forces to Hindi from S India in the 60s]

Answer (score 0):

**Population**
As the maps in [@ohwilleke's answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/74986/44276) demonstrate, the status of Hindi in India and Urdu in Pakistan is not the same. 
India has a large population fraction with native language Hindi, while Pakistan has a quite low fraction speaking Urdu natively.

***lingua franca*** 
Also,

> practically, both of them are the lingua franca in their respective countries.

This is not true to a large extent. I'm unaware of the details in Pakistan, but in India there's no singular lingua franca. In most of the South Indian regions, and many people in Mumbai, cannot (or are not willing to) speak/understand Hindi. They use English to communicate if they don't speak the same native language. There are large rural sections in India where Hindi is irrelevant.

**The Constitutions**
When [the Constitution of India](https://legislative.gov.in/sites/default/files/COI_English.pdf) was made, it was made with the idea that within 15 years, Hindi would be accepted by all, and will replace English. However, this proved to be unsuccessful (i.e. English continues to be used where Hindi should have been) due to it being seen as "Hindi imposition" by many non-Hindi speaking regions. Therefore, while  the official language of *the
Union* (government) is Hindi in Devanagari script, it is not the official/national language of (the Republic of) *India*.

[The Pakistani constitution](https://na.gov.pk/uploads/documents/1333523681_951.pdf) specifies Urdu to be the national language of Pakistan as per the 1973 constitution. It also asks for "arrangements to be made for use of Urdu for official and other
purposes"  - which has been implemented in Pakistan.  Also, [a constitutional amendment in 1985](https://www.pakistani.org/pakistan/constitution/orders/po14_1985.html#:%7E:text=preferably%20be%20made%20in%20Urdu) asks for constitutional oaths to be preferably made in Urdu.